# How do you write a test for dynamic API content?

Tags: testing

I am working on a wrapper for an API, and one of the endpoints returns data that doesn't have the same results each time.

What is a good strategy to test that the endpoint is still valid?

This is a general question, although I am mostly interested in getting this to work in Python.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't have the same results each time'?

Comment: @axlj I get a JSON response, but the exact JSON string doesn't match what the other tests can do.

Comment: At lease an example?

Comment: For example: https://api.github.com/events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define what you actually expect from the result. What are the statements that always hold for the result?

Popular candidates/examples are

- it is valid JSON/HTML/XML
- it contains certain substrings
- it has certain "fields"
- certain fields can be parsed as a date using a specific format, and the resulting date is within +/-1h of now.

Comment: I think testing against the fields will suffice. Thanks!